# Has this Principal Component Analysis (PCA) been done correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a set of **3D data points**, indicated by the **blue** color in the picture below.

I then **project them onto the x-y plane**, i.e. setting z values of all the points to 0, shown by the **yellow** color below.

Then, I perform PCA on the 2D data points (the yellow ones).

I end up with the **1st Principal Component** being the **green** line, and the 2nd being the yellow line.

[image]

As I am a newbie in PCA, I am not sure whether I have done something wrong or not.

Because in my intuitive, the 1st Principal Component should be like in the picture below:

[image]

*I mean unlike the above picture given in wiki, my 1st component is NOT obvious and seems to make no sense.* **Did I do something wrong?**

**Edit:**

To avoid the confusion, the 2D view from the above is as follows:
[image]

Comment: It's hard to see from the picture, but I think your 2D axis does not seem to have the origin at the 2D mean.

Comment: By the way, why do your points come as triples?

Comment: @Tunococ  as tripples? they are 3D accelerations. And I am only interested in x-y accelerations. So I did the projection. Please see the edited question. I post the 2D view up.

Comment: I meant triples of points. Like, there are always three points close together.
Anyway, can you confirm if your 2D data points have zero mean?

Comment: @Tunococ  oh, I guess it is because only one of the accelerations changes each time. So they come in triples. U mean I should place my origin at the mean?

Comment: That is what I meant. You want to subtract the mean from all the points before doing PCA (if your PCA library doesn't do that for you).

Comment: @Tunococ  may I know the reason for that? What if I don't do that. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not do that, the result would correspond to fitting a Gaussian to a distribution with a known mean. (That means computing only the sample covariance matrix.) There is nothing wrong with it if you know what you are doing. It is just a little unusual, and you cannot expect the picture to look like what you think your result is supposed to look like.